# Integral approximation Taylor polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

$ f(x) = e^{x^2}/2 $

Approximate the integral $\int _{-1}^1\:f(x)\,dx$ using Taylor polynomials.

Can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: use the identity expansion $ exp(x^2) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$

Comment: @JoseGarcia Proper notation is $\exp(x^2)$, not $exp(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\exp u = 1 + u + \frac{u^2} 2 + \frac{u^3} 6 + \frac{u^4}{24} + \frac{u^5}{120} + \cdots.
$$
$$ u = x^2. $$
Add up the first several terms and integrate from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: As it is in the OP, I think $u$ should just be $x^2$. The $\frac{1}{2}$ isn't in the exponent of $\mathrm{e}$.